# Find the curvature

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

If a point moves along a curve so that the velocity and acceletation vectors have constant lenght, how to proove that the curvature is also a constant?

Comment: The curvature is the norm of the derivative of the unit tangent vector...

Comment: Hmm...so what please?

Comment: What is the length of the acceleration vector? Can you make the link with the velocity vector, and then with also the unit tangent vector...?

Comment: That vector is the acceleration.. and the velocity being constant ensures that the curve is parametrized by a multiple of arc-lenght

Comment: But how to prove this using the definitions?

Comment: No, Martigan, not yet. Can you expand that hint?

Comment: If the angle between velocity and acceleration can change I doubt that we have a constant curvature.

Comment: Can you write down your definition of curvature of a curve?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Since both velocity and acceleration have a constant norm...

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $T$ the unit tangent vector, $v$ the velocity vector and $a$ the acceleration vector, and $\kappa$ the curvature.

$T=\dfrac{v}{||v||}$, $a=\dfrac{dv}{ds}$, $\kappa=||\dfrac{dT}{ds}||$ by definition.

Can you take it from here?

EDIT: let's call $\lambda=||v||$ since this is constant.

Then you have $\kappa=\frac{1}{\lambda}||a||$

But since $a$ is of constant length, then $\kappa$ is constant as well.

Comment: I am aware of these formula, but I am not sure I can go further. Sorry.

Comment: @Bello See my update

Comment: Sounds right. Thanks!